# Using Angular and nginx I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: angular, typescript, nginx, wavesurfer.js

I see many people having problems with this but almost all seem to be using react.  This is my first project in Angular (8.2.9) and nginx.  I have been working on the project for awhile and it works great when just use ng serve but I get this error after doing a prod build and serving on nginx.  It is in the main-es2015... file.  If I comment this script out of the index.html file that is generated it will at least load the index.html file without error.

From looking at the questions about this error with react it seems to be mainly about extending a class incorrectly or circular inheritance. I went through all my imports and they seem to be correct.  The only one that is different is for the wavesurfer.js package.  After importing the types for wavesurfer.js I had to import using

```
import  * as WaveSurfer  from 'wavesurfer.js';
```

This seems to work fine locally so not sure this is my problem but it would seem to be the only import that is different than the standard imports.

Not sure where to start looking.  If anyone has some ideas of where to start looking or how to determine what exactly is throwing this error I would appreciate it.

---

### Solved

Finally did narrow it down to the import of wavesurfer.js.  After a day of trying different imports, compiler flags, etc. it came down to just changing my import statement to :

```
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js/dist/wavesurfer';
```

Seems to work locally with ng serve and after ng build --prod and served with nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found through trial and error but seems to be working now.